# .NET : System.Threading.ThreadStart Class

Tags: .net, clr, specifications

I have questions about System.Threading.ThreadStart Class :

- where can I find its specifications ( there is praticly nothing in the msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx or in ROTOR : www.dotnet247.com/247reference/system/threading/threadstart/__rotor.aspx)
- what is its field : protected System.IntPtr _methodPtrAux

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you got ROTOR, you should have been able to answer at least one of your questions:

```
    // In the case of a static method passed to a delegate, this field stores
    // whatever _methodPtr would have stored: and _methodPtr points to a
    // small thunk which removes the "this" pointer before going on
    // to _methodPtrAux.
    internal IntPtr _methodPtrAux;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) ThreadStart is a delegate, not a class.  It is a variable that holds a pointer to a method.  In this case, it is any method that takes no parameters and returns no variable.  So you can do something like this:

```
private void SomeMethod() {}

public void StartThreadingLol()
{
  var thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
}
```

2) Whatever field that is it doesn't have anything to do with you as a .NET programmer.  Why do you think you need it?

Comment: _methodPtrAux is the address of the method the delegate points to, correct ? (in your example, the address of SomeMethod()).